# Summary -> Detail Views/Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a general pattern that is recommended for building a "summary detail" type view? Say for example, you have an invoicing app with a reporting view that needs to list headings for every customer with a detail of every open invoice for that customer under the heading.

Here's how I've attempted to deal with it in the past (using the customer/invoice example), none of which has been very satisfactory:

**Method #1**:

Create a join query which joins the customer details with the invoice. In the view loop over the collection using an instance variable to keep track of the customer being looped over. Have a conditional in the loop code that compares the current iteration's customer with the last interation's customer. If they are different, add in a heading for the new customer.

**Method #2**:

Query for customers with an open invoice, then in the view iterate over the customers and nested the customer iteration, do another iteration over that customer's open invoices, e.g:

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <%= customer.name %>
  <% customer.invoices.open.each do |invoice| %>
    <%= invoice.details %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So, yeah. Neither one of these feels great. Method #1 seems like a hack and Method #2 seems like it would generate too many queries though its the most readable in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a classical case to use ActiveRecord includes option

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

so in your controller where to find customers

```
Customer.includes(:invoices).where('customer.name = ?', 'example')
```

Comment: And then just use the second method w/ the nested interations?

Comment: sorry yes should have mentioned that too.. will preload them into memory saving db trips..